# How do I use the Time Machine command line interface to backup to an internal ip server?

Tags: time-machine

I have a Time Machine server which uses a manually defined internal ip (not dhcp assigned.) It is using 169.254.x.x this case.

How do I use the Time Machine command line interface to configure backups?

**UPDATE:** The Time Machine Server is a QNAP NAS server. I make the DHCP off on my router. I am able to connect to it via 169.254.x.x to the server either.

I can't get known the Time Machine on the client site via the Time Machine client tool. So, I just wonder to use cli to connect to the Time Machine server.

I make an explanation for that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Why would the IP matter? You need to edit this to explain what “backup it via cli” means. This could mean how does the unnamed server host back itself up or a request to trigger other clients or a request to set up other clients. Seems like about 4 pieces need to come together if all of my assumptions are correct.

Comment: @bmike I guess his main problem is that he can't connect to an intranet ip address.

Comment: No part of Time Machine needs internet access @maP1EbluE - but I appreciate the collaborative effort to see if we can understand what's being asked.

Comment: Is your server in the same LAN as your mac?

Comment: Thanks to all first. I did connect to the server which is a NAS. It own Time Machine server. I make the DHCP server of router disable. So, I use 169.254.x.x to connect to the NAS and I am able to connect to NAS. It is ok. But, possibly the matter is on disable DHCP function on router. Time Machine client site is unable to connect to the Time Machine. In addition, this is why I want to use cli to connect to that NAS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure a client to backup to a remote server, you use the **tmutil** command, and the **setdestination** verb.

```
tmutil setdestination afp://user[:pass]@169.254.x.x/share
```

This also assumes that you have **share** already existing as an AFP share on your TimeMachine server.

TimeMachine from client-side doesn't really care much about the remote server, except to mount the AFP volume.